# How to connect to mysql database and retrieve data from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL Db in the below javascript function.The funcion however does not execute.Can someone please tell me how to connect to MySQL DB and retrieve data through a JS function?

```
function jsfunction(projectSelected){

  alert("hi");
   document.getElementById("total").value = projectSelected;
   a="hi";

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/service", "root", "root");
   Statement st4=con.createStatement();

   ResultSet rs4=st4.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project= '"+project_selected+"' " );

  String total_amount=rs.getString("total_amount");


}
```

Comment: You mess javascript and java code. I'm absolutely sure that you have no idea what are you doing.

Comment: I am trying to change value of a text box based on the selection of a drop down.I am a beginner here with limited knowledge of Java,JS,HTML,JSP

Answer (score -2):

You should not use js for sql query. I would do it through a request with AJAX which will execute a php document.

Read this article and get to know how:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

PS: Sorry for my barely available english skills

PPS: I have made a function some time ago that maybe can be usefull for you:

```
function request(url,value,output_id,output){

    $.post(url,
    {
      value: value,
      output_id:output_id,

    },
    function(data,status){
        if(status==="success"){
         if(output===1){
          alert(data);
          alert("||value"+value)
         }
         if(output_id!=0){

         document.getElementById(output_id).innerHTML =data;
         }
        }
    });}
```

**Usage**
You have to hand over the id of a httml element(output_id)where you want the result to be shown, a value which will be sent to the php file and the name of the file(url).

**The PhP file**
To use the value in the php file of your choise, you just have to add this little line somewhere:

```
$php_value = strtoupper($_POST['value']);
```